# Ideal generated by two relatively prime polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $f(x,y),g(x,y)\in\mathbb R[x,y]$ such that $\gcd(f(x,y),g(x,y))=1$.

Let also $I\triangleleft\mathbb R[x,y]$ be the ideal generated by $f(x,y), g(x,y)$.

$I=\langle f(x,y),g(x,y)\rangle$

What can we say it's true about the ideal, what properties does it have?

My guess is since the polynomials are relatively prime then $I\equiv R[x,y]$. Is this true? If not is there anything else that can be said about the properties of the ideal?

Comment: @DonAntonio $R[x,y]$ is not a Bézout domain. For instance, $(x,y)\ne (1)$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Good catch. Didn't even noticed it was two unknowns...

Comment: The special case of polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ and _field_ $R$ already has a variety of possibilities, and the computation of the quotient can be done step-wise.